# Deployment Targets with Health Check "Unavailable" in Octopus

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, bamboo, octopus-deploy, azure-vm-role

Now my company asked us to integrate Octopus with Bamboo. We were already using Bamboo for building and running the Unit Test cases.
So this is the process which I followed.
1. Installed the Octopus server and created package and pushed it. Followed this [link](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/bamboo) .
2. Created an environment in Octopus like Development,QA etc.
3. Installed the Octopus tentacle in one of the Azure Virtual Machines. Followed this [link](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/windows-targets/azure-virtual-machines).
4. Added Azure VM Extension following this [link](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/windows-targets/azure-virtual-machines/via-the-azure-portal). In this link , it is mentioned that as soon as we add extension in Azure portal, after few minutes, it will be visible Octopus Deploy server.
"After a few minutes, the machine should appear in the environments tab of your Octopus Deploy Server".

And as mentioned, it is visible in environments tab,  but it is saying `unavailable` like shown in the image.

[image: Error Message]

I have also attached the logs which was generated while attempting a connection with Azure VM, if it helps.

```
Recent Communication Logs
August 8th 2018 20:14:21Info
Opening a new connection 
August 8th 2018 20:14:42Error
Unexpected exception executing transaction. Halibut.HalibutClientException: The client was unable to establish the initial connection within 00:01:00
   at Halibut.Transport.TcpClientExtensions.ConnectWithTimeout(TcpClient client, String host, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\TcpClientExtensions.cs:line 43
   at Halibut.Transport.TcpClientExtensions.ConnectWithTimeout(TcpClient client, Uri remoteUri, TimeSpan timeout) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\TcpClientExtensions.cs:line 13
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.CreateConnectedTcpClient(ServiceEndPoint endPoint) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 168
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.EstablishNewConnection() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 148
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.ExecuteTransaction(Action`1 protocolHandler) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 69
August 8th 2018 20:14:43Error
Retry attempt 1 
August 8th 2018 20:14:43Info
Opening a new connection 
August 8th 2018 20:15:04Error
Unexpected exception executing transaction. Halibut.HalibutClientException: The client was unable to establish the initial connection within 00:01:00
   at Halibut.Transport.TcpClientExtensions.ConnectWithTimeout(TcpClient client, String host, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\TcpClientExtensions.cs:line 43
   at Halibut.Transport.TcpClientExtensions.ConnectWithTimeout(TcpClient client, Uri remoteUri, TimeSpan timeout) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\TcpClientExtensions.cs:line 13
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.CreateConnectedTcpClient(ServiceEndPoint endPoint) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 168
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.EstablishNewConnection() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 148
   at Halibut.Transport.SecureClient.ExecuteTransaction(Action`1 protocolHandler) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\3db141632c8c5dde\source\Halibut\Transport\SecureClient.cs:line 69
```

I didn't understand this and couldn't find any solutions on the internet.
So if anyone has any idea about what this error is or if anyone is faced with similar issue and were successful in solving it, some insights would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the server cannot make a connection back to the tentacle, which defaults to port 10933. You will need to open up this port in the Azure VM Firewall